# Geração de PDF atráves de um HTML em PHP muito lento

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf, exportação

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP que tem um módulo para a exportação em PDF de uma determinada informação que gero em HTML, porém esse processo está muito lento, pois creio que é muita informação (em média 40 páginas);

A lib que estou usando é o [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

Código que uso para a exportação:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->loadHtml($meuhtml);
$dompdf->setPaper("A4", "portrait");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("meupdf.pdf", array("Attachment" => TRUE));
```

Já li a documentação do dompdf e vi que a comunidade fala muito da lentidão da biblioteca porém não vejo muitas alternativas.

Conheço a biblioteca [Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) também, porém como ela utiliza o [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) acabo não conseguindo utilizar, pois o sistema está em uma hospedagem compartilhada.

Como posso melhorar o desempenho para a exportação de PDF?

Comment: Este conteúdo html costuma ficar alterando sempre? o que poderia ser feito é salvar o pdf já renderizado no servidor e quando o usuário fizer a requisição ele acessa esse arquivo já salvo

Comment: @ThiagoCosta O HTML não é fixo e ele é feito através de uma consulta ao banco de dados, ou seja, as informações são dinâmicas conforme o usuário usa o sistema para gerar os relatórios.

Comment: @zuguhu já passei por este problema e utilizando a mesma biblioteca dompdf. No meu caso decidi trocar e geração do pdf do dompdf para o um puglin em Javascript. no meio caso foi uma mão na roda quanto a performance. 
Dá uma pesquisada por "pdf via javascript", pode ser uma opção.

Comment: @MarcusItalo Então, cheguei a pesquisa e as bibliotecas que encontrei, a maioria precisam do node para funcionar e como uso hospedagem compartilhada, não consigo utiliza-las, consegue dizer uma biblioteca que me atenda sem precisar do próprio node?

Comment: @zuguhu tem puglins em jQuery, ou você pode fazer sua própria biblioteca.Uma opção é via popup e manda imprimir [exemplo](http://www.macoratti.net/18/09/js_pdf1.htm). Não é necessário utilizar node, só script .js . Desculpa não lembrar qual a biblioteca especifica.